# Turn off JavaScript notifications in IE9 and FireFox4

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, firefox4

In web development, JavaScript is often executed when clicking on elements.

In both Internet Explorer 9 and FireFox 4 a little message pops up in the bottom left hand corner with the JavaScript function will be executed by clicking on elements these elements.

ASP.NET makes use of the JavaScript __doPostback(...ugly parameter names..) on almost every element that sends a request to the server. This JavaScript is automatically added to the HTML elements that are generated by the ASP.NET controls and I have no way to circumvent this.

For example, an ASP.NET DropDownList is rendered as an HTML Select element and the __doPostBack() method is added to it so that whenever the user selects a new element, the server can process this action.

The __doPostaback() method is embedded into many of the ASP.NET controls and there is no easy way to change this.

One of my end users commented that this new feature makes it feel as if they are in "Debug-mode"....

So, my question is: how do I either make this popup show something user friendly...or is there a way to tell the browser (via HTML) not to display this nastiness?

Thanks!

-Frinny

Comment: I suggest not putting JavaScript into your links, and using actual event listeners on the elements instead.

Comment: ASP.NET automatically inserts JavaScript into the HTML elements for the developer. I cannot change this without an immense amount of effort. It's not just "links" that this JavaScript is added to, drop-down-lists (the HTML select-elements), buttons, etc etc all have this code automatically inserted into them.

Comment: I suggest not using ASP.NET and instead writing HTML you have control over.

Comment: Haha :) Nice one. If this were a simple application then I would consider it. But it's not exactly small or simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make the `href` of the link a hashtag and attach the *actual* action via JavaScript:

```
HTML
<a id="foo" href="#foo">Foo</a>

JS
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.onclick = function(e){
  //script foo!
  return false;
};
```

Your location will still be `#foo` to look nice, but the *actual* action will be in the `foo.onclick` function.

Alternatively you can specify the event inline (`<a href="foo" onclick="return foo();">Foo</a>`), but I try to keep a clear MVC separation with HTML, CSS, & JS.

Using a hashtag also gives you the ability to listen for hash-change events or check the hash tag onload so that a user can still middle-click a link and have it work correctly in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there isn't a way to make it not display, as that is part of the browser and not the page.

What I would do is create javascript functions at the top of the page with user readable names that contain the other functions inside.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That sounds feasible in a non-ASP.NET development environment...but not so feasible in this case.

Comment: @Frinavale in theory you can turn it off in `about:config` somewhere in FF4. Good luck finding it.